# CollectionView nested inside Collectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewdelegate

I have seen solutions where a collection view is nested inside a table view but for my app I need to have 2 collection views as it makes it easier to do some other things.

So lets call the root collection view **VerticalCollectionView** which only scrolls vertically and the nested collection view **HorizontalCollectionView** which only scrolls horizontally. I created them using the Storyboard. Below you'll see the orange is the Vertical with the green Horizontal with a label inside it.

[image]

[image]

And I have set the delegate & datasource of both collections to the same CollectionViewController. [image]

I distinguish between the 2 different cells by checking which tableview the delegate method is referencing as such
[image]

My problem is that HorizontalCollectionView isn't getting instantiated. I have everything working for VerticalCollectionView, the background color, the number of items, etc. In the VerticalCollectionViewCell, I have an IBOutlet referencing HorizontalCollectionView

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try reloading your horizontal collectionView inside the call for cellForRow for the vertical collection view

Comment: Manually call `reloadData` on `collectionView`.

Comment: Tried reloading data in cellForRow for the vertical and inside awakeFromNib in the verticalCell and I get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
"

Answer (score 4):

I have used nested collectionViews in my recent app a lot. at first it didn't work for me but when I learned its away it became pretty simple.

instead of setting the HorizontalCollectionView delegate and dataSource to the same CollectionViewController make a UICollectionViewCell and set the delegates and dataSource in `awakeFromNib()` function of the cell and write the HorizontalCollectionView functions in that cell. it works like a charm ;)

if you needed more detailed answer let me know.

Comment: I have a table view that the cell of that table view has a horizontal paging collection view and In this collection view there is another collection view But the problem is that when I change the table view cell height the collection view won't fit to the cell But I used constraints in story board

Comment: if the collectionView does not fit, along with the constraint(which I assume you gave correct constraints) try implementing these 4 delegate functions for collectionView and give the size of cell according to the height of tableView 
`sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath -> CGSize {}
minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int -> CGFloat {}
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int -> CGFloat {}
insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {}`

Comment: so here is all my codes can you help me please to do that ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850234/the-collection-view-inside-table-view-cells-wont-fit-to-the-cell-even-after-con

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking here since WWDC 19, Apple has introduced CompositionalLayout for UICollectionViews which make these tasks much much easier.

One should read here:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/215/

Comment: Note that this is for iOS 13+