# UIcollectionview inside UIcollectionviewcell and how to display data

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I need to create a `collectionView A` contains few types of cells. One of the cell contains `collectionView B` that can scroll horizontally. So `collectionView A` will scroll vertically.

Can I know how to create it and how to display the data into `collectionView B`?

Thanks again guys

Comment: Please have a look on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273765/collectionview-nested-inside-collectionview

Comment: And this library may help you. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/insights-for-instagram

Comment: you mean like Appstore? Why not use `sections`. In `numberOfSections` and `numberOfItemsInSection`.

Comment: @aBilal17 will take a look bro..thanks

Comment: @Haitus I think more like a Instagram, can created it with your way?

Comment: @karenr, instagram, messenger, App Store that you scan swipe horizontal and vertical - Yes. Set like ... layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout() layout.scrollDirection to either .vertical or horizontal

Comment: @Haitus is there any link or guide to check out? Because I am super new to swift and ios, thanks ya bro

Comment: @karenr, Likewise, you could search in youtube the channel of lets build that app(I'm not endorsing) where he replicates App Store without storyboard. Or that library above, you could tweak it to your liking. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Collection A have Cells  lets call our target cell  as `ASubCell`

then at `ASubCell` we will have `Collection B`  with all of its delegate , and you will create delegate say `ASubCellDelegate` to send action on  `Collection B` to ViewController of `Collection A` , here example

```
import UIKit

protocol ASubCellDelegate {
    // CollectionView Cell Pressed
    func onSubCellAtcolectionBPressed(_item : YourData)
}
class ASubCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewB : UICollectionView!
     var delegate : ASubCellDelegate?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        // setup your Collection View B
    }

}


// set up your horizontal Collection View
extension UICollectionViewCell:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell  =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "YourBCellID", for: indexPath) as! YourBCellID
        return cell
    }
    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if delegate != nil {
            self.onSubCellAtcolectionBPressed(YourData)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: bro, I need to load all the data on the main view controller then display the data to both the collectionview A and B, not by clicking the cell.

Comment: Yes you will Pass dataSource of collection be to cell of collection A  , that what will done